# python will not release memory for tuple, will it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-leaks, tuples, backend

According to this article I read, it looks like immutable type may become immortal.

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm

I am currently working on solve a memory usage problem for my web service which running on google app engine. Does "use too much tuple" could be a potential reason to cause this problem?

---

Thanks for the reply:
I am running my code on google app engine backend instance and it has a memory usage upper bounds (128mb). It said I use more memory than allowed and stopped my instance. As comments mentioned, It could be "memory usage remain large" instead of "memory leaks".

Comment: "Memory leak" is subtly different from "memory usage *remains* large after a brief period of high memory usage" (that's what that article describes) in my book. Could you clarify which is the case? As the article says, it *will* re-used space - it simply will set aside a large chunk of memory for future large allocations and not return it voluntarily.

Comment: I agree with delnan, the article doesn't say anything about tuples or immutable types.  I don't know why your question focuses on tuples

Comment: Some ideas to help troubleshoot your memory issues:  If you `import resource; print resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)[2]` you can get a snapshot of the current maximum resident set size, or `cat /proc/18444/status` will show detailed memory info for a process.  More good stuff: http://mg.pov.lt/blog/hunting-python-memleaks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article doesn't specify immutable types - it specifies:

> Another possible cause for excessive memory usage is that Python uses so-called “free lists” for certain object types, including integers and floats.

I don't know what information you can get on a GAE process, but you can try this experiment on your own system.

First, start up a python interpreter and find the process. Then run this command:

```
>>> many_tuples = [() for x in range(5000000)] #replace with xrange for 2.x
```

Then, take a look at the memory usage. You've just created a list of 5 million tuples. Now type:

```
>>> del many_tuples
```

On my system (Python 3.2, Win 7), my memory usage shot up about 20k, and then dropped by the same amount once I `del`ed the variable. If you can get information about your processes (CPU, memory usage), you can try doing that - maybe several times in a row which should give you a few spikes of higher memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in the article you linked that tuples are one of the types for which Python maintains its own free lists. They could well be, but according to [this article](http://www.evanjones.ca/memoryallocator/) the specific culprits are `int`s, `float`s, `dict`s, and `list`s. Although that article is from 2005 and things could have changed since then...

In Python 2.6 or later, the free lists for everything but `int`s and `float`s can be cleared with with `gc.collect(2)`, which I guess doesn't help you on GAE, but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

The immutable type does not become immortal.  The memory it occupied is still owned by Python, but it is available for use for other objects.

Circular dependencies is a possibility for your memory leak:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.offspring = Child(self)
    def __del__(self):
        # doesn't matter what goes here, gc will not be able to auto collect
        # freed Parents and Childs

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

John_Doe = Parent()
```

At this point you have a `Child` with a link to its `Parent`, and a `Parent` with a link to its `Child`, and Python may have trouble releasing them.